# Python path file from command line

Tags: python, csv

I have a working script as below but i have a little problem when i try to launch the script from windows command line or from the windows task manager.

When i run the script from pycharm or IDLE it works like a charm. But when i try to use commande line like this:

py -2.7 "C:\Users\bob\Google Drive\pycharmpoject\flux_update\ajout_data.py"

It does not work. It says IOError:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\source_csv\drop\drop-2015-07-09.csv

It looks like is missing the path which is C:\Users\bob\Google Drive\pycharmpoject\flux_update\source_csv\drop-2015-07-09.csv

Any idea

```
import csv
import datetime
import shutil

#Declaration du jour

jour = datetime.date.today()

InFile  = os.path.abspath('../source_csv/drop-'+str(jour)+'.csv')
OutFile = os.path.abspath('../source_csv/drop_updated-'+str(jour)+'.csv')

#ajout des columns necessaires

with open(InFile, 'r') as csvinput:
    with open(OutFile, 'wb') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput, delimiter=",")
    '''next(reader)'''

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        for row in reader:

            if float(row[6]) < 20:
                row.append(float(row[6])*(0.88*1.53))
                row.append(2.99)
            elif float(row[6]) < 40:
                row.append(float(row[6])*(0.88*1.40)-6.99)
                row.append(7.99)
            else:
                row.append(float(row[6])*(0.88*1.30)-29.99)
                row.append(29.99)

            all.append(row)

        for row in reader:
            row.append(row)
            all.append(row)

        writer.writerow( ('name','description') )
        writer.writerows(all)
```

Comment: Try appending an `r` before the file paths to turn it into a raw string, like so `r'hello world'`.

Comment: Hi, It does not work even with 'r'

Comment: Check out @jacdeh's answer then. Surely your pointing to the wrong directory.

Answer (score 1):

The relative paths in your script are interpreted relative TO YOUR CURRENT DIRECTORY.

If you have to type commands as long as:
py -2.7 "C:\Users\bob\Google Drive\pycharmpoject\flux_update\ajout_data.py"
your current directory most likely is not "C:\Users\bob\Google Drive\pycharmpoject\flux_update" as it should be.